# Method not being called

Tags: objective-c, methods, xcode4.2, call, nsurl

I have a fairly simple method in a class in a separate file, which takes in an integer, looks it up in a case select, and returns an NSURL pointer that corresponds to it. It has this method:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ChangeCurrentScene : NSObject
{
    NSString *filePath;
    NSURL *url;
    int currentScene;
}

- (NSURL *)changeSceneURL:(int)toDesiredScene;

@end
```

I'm not 100% sure how I'm supposed to call it from outside, but I have a button hooked up in my storyboard, which definitely works, and I'm using this line to call it:

```
 nextURL = [sceneChanger changeSceneURL:1];
```

From this header file:

```
@interface MSViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    BOOL userInputAvailable;
    int currentScene;
    NSURL *nextURL;
    ChangeCurrentScene *sceneChanger;

}

@property (strong) AVAudioPlayer *menuPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userChoiceLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *nowPlayingIcon;


- (BOOL) playScene : (NSURL *)fileToBePlayed;

@end
```

I've put a breakpoint on the first line of the changeSceneURL:toDesiredScene class, but it is not called at all. No crashes, but no calls either. First off, is this the correct way to use the return from a called method? nextURL is an NSURL object, and I want the returned value to be stored in it. Secondly, what reason would there be for the method not being called at all? I'm really stumped here, but I'm sure it's something blindingly simple.

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Can you show the header file for the object with the name sceneChanger ? That object should be where the method changeSceneURL:is located. But something else could be happening, so add the entire header file to your original question.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `nextURL=` line, and check the value of sceneChanger. It is probably nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chech that `sceneChanger` is not `nil`. You can send messages to `nil`, but the method doesn't get called.

**Edit** You should initialize `sceneChanger` somewhere like this:

```
sceneChanger = [[ChangeCurrentScene alloc] init];
```

Comment: Yes, it is nil. I tested in gdb with "po sceneChanger". How do I assign a value to it? Do I need to assign an NSURL to it, or an int? It's a method, I wasn't aware a method had a value.

Comment: @lukech - No, `sceneChanger` is an object, it is an instance of `ChangeCurrentScene`.